# Customization of "Choose app" dialog

Tags: android, dialog

When user tries to open some url in my android app a "Choose app" dialog appeared. Can this dialog be customized? At least I need to change its header text, but it'd be great if it is also possible to remove some entries from the dialog.

Comment: I don't think so, as it is the way your system choose to interpret the url's intents...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Intent.createChooser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) to open explicitely the chooser. You can pass it a title.

Answer (score 1):

The right way "to remove some entries from the dialog" is to limit your Intent by putting more strict filters on them (package/category/action, etc).

If you can't limit your Intent to a smaller scope, you will need a way to filter through them, which I don't think it's possible.